# Issue opening a webpage with Chrome using 'webbrowser'

Tags: python-webbrowser

My default web browser is Firefox. When I run this code:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("https://google.com")
```

Firefox shows up and opens the specified url page.

But I want to open the page with Chrome. So I tried:

```
chrome_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open("https://google.com")
```

Then I get `Error: could not locate runnable browser` message.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the chrome driver to run it.
You can download ChromeDriver here:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Then you have multiple [options](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver):

- add it to your system `path`
- put it in the same directory as your python script
- specify the location directly via `executable_path`

  ```
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe')
  ```

Upd:
To handle it you can go it:

in cmd line

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

and in python

```
from selenium import webdriver

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I downloaded the driver and added it to my system path, which appears on command prompt but didn't work. Then I put the .exe file in the same directory as my script, which didn't work. So I added selenium (webdriver) and tried the third way, which gives me a message: `WebDriverException: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. [...]`. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm testing this with Spyder 4.1.5.

Comment: I have chrome version 86.0.4240.111 and downloaded ChromeDriver 86.0.4240.22

Comment: im glad to know ^^